# Highcharts, obtain json/serialized chart object options?

Tags: highcharts

i need to do something, i tried everything but i cannot get what i want.
I have one chart in one container, and at some point a have to render that chart to another div, but without losing the first one, so... i need to duplicate that chart but in a new container.

Im able to get the chart that im refering to, but i need something like getting the options of this chart so i can initialize another chart, with same options but in a different container.

The chart is generated dinamically, so i do not have the options before it is rendered, so the only way i can get the option in order to replicate the chart i getting the options of an already painted chart.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: Please refer the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) guide for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `chart.userOptions` property to get the options needed to create a second chart:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }],
    xAxis: {
        max: 10
    }
});

$('#duplicate').on('click', function() {
    Highcharts.chart('container2', chart.userOptions);
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9q70mvky/

Comment: Cool, that works. Easier than i thought xd.
Thank you!